# running Jupyter notebook using ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have recently installed glib-2.17 in Oracle Linux 6.9 which previously had glibc-2.14. I now have both glibcs in different folders. I need this glibc-2.17 in order to run python libraries like TensorFlow or Keras.

I can launch python 2.7 (installed as part of Anaconda2) using this:

```
/opt/glibc-2.17/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /home/oracle/anaconda2/bin/python
```

I can import tensorflow 1.2 and keras libraries successfully.

However, when I open a jupyter notebook (python2 kernel) I cannot import tensorflow and throws an error related to:

Is there a way to launch the python2 kernel in Jupyter using the command:

```
/opt/glibc-2.17/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /home/oracle/anaconda2/bin/python
```

Answer (score 0):

Installed using `conda install tensorflow` and `conda install kera`s and they both work on Jupyter notebooks as well.

Not sure why though.